# Dictionary type "Phone book" Open Hashing? and Possibly Linked List?

Tags: c, data-structures

i'm doing a self project or call it what you will, i'm creating a phone book - dictionary type which allows **UNLIMITED** unique Names and per Names allows **UNLIMITED** phone numbers so pretty much linked list all the way right? an yeah no static arrays... :/ since it data is unlimited so to speak.. so my question is...IS THERE A BETTER WAY? anyone has some ideas? unlimited yet unique person names then each person can have unlimted set of phone numbers?

Comment: You could try a sort of ordered tree, such that the path from the root spells the name you are looking for.

Comment: Some sort of hash-table for persons and phone-numbers will probably speed up lookup. But why not put the data in a database instead? A simple database like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is probably best, especially if you want to save data between runs.

Comment: You gave only half the information to your problem: what will be the main use case of your phone book? It is pointless to ask for a data structure if it is not clear what you want to do with it. And if you are earnest in your "unlimited" requirement, one of your main concerns will be to handle unlimited persistent data (in your file system or data base) which is a whole complex task in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a self-balancing binary search tree or some sort of hash table.

More info see below.

[Self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

[Hash-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Implementing it as a hash table might be simpler if you've never done this before.  I'd recommend reading a book on algorithms and data structures.  Some resources follow.

[The algorithm design manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Steven-Skiena/dp/1848000693)

[Algorithms by Sedgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X)

[Algorithms in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201756080)

Of course if you are not interested in the details you can use an existing library for this or some sort of database.

Comment: thanks and sorry for the late reply, i always forget to check back on stackoverflow.